# update a nested object in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, kibana

i hope i can find some help

my problem is that i am triying to update a nasted object that i have.

here 's my index architecture

```
{
  "grille_badge" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "theme" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "categories" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "niveaux" : {
                  "type" : "nested",
                  "properties" : {
                    "grille_defis" : {
                      "type" : "nested",
                      "properties" : {
                        "defis" : {
                          "type" : "nested",
                          "properties" : {
                            "name" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "name" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "name" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is exemple of my document that i wand to edit

```
{
  "_index" : "grille_badge",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "theme" : [
      {
        "name" : "foot",
        "categories" : [
          {
            "name" : "categorie1",
            "niveaux" : [
              {
                "name" : "bronze",
                "grille_defis" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "grille1",
                    "defis" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name" : "categorie2",
            "niveaux" : [
              {
                "name" : "argent",
                "grille_defis" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "grille1",
                    "defis" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name" : "categorie3",
            "niveaux" : [
              {
                "name" : "or",
                "grille_defis" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "grille1",
                    "defis" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And i am triying to add a Defis to my empty list, like the code below that i found in the documentation

```
POST index_name/_update/doc_id
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.cats.add(params.cat)",
    "params": {
      "cat": {
        "colors": 4,
        "name": "Leon",
        "breed": "Persian"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i tried to make my own script that can go deep into my defis list but still don't know how to do it.

here's what i tried to do

```
POST grille_badge/_update/1
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def theme_target = ctx._source.theme.findAll(our_theme theme.name == params.current_theme); def categorie_target = theme_target.findAll(our_categorie categories.name == params.current_categorie); def niveau_target = categorie_target.findAll(our_niveau niveaux.name == params.current_niveau); def grille_target = niveau_target.findAll(our_grille grille_defis.name == params.current_grille); grille_target.defis.add(params.defis_ajouter)",
    "params": {
      "current_theme": "foot",
      "current_categorie": "categorie1",
      "current_niveau": "niveau1",
      "current_grille": "grille1",
      "defis_ajouter": "i am a defis"
    }
  }
}
```

please could anyone help me !!

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Your question is quite confusing but here's how you update a doc by a script where your params are an instance of `HashMap`:

1. Index the original document w/ an id of `1` -- collapsed for brevity:

```
POST grille_badge/_doc/1
{"theme":[{"name":"foot","categories":[{"name":"categorie1","niveaux":[{"name":"bronze","grille_defis":[{"name":"grille1","defis":[]}]}]},{"name":"categorie2","niveaux":[{"name":"argent","grille_defis":[{"name":"grille1","defis":[]}]}]},{"name":"categorie3","niveaux":[{"name":"or","grille_defis":[{"name":"grille1","defis":[]}]}]}]}]}
```

2. Update doc#1 (note that you can also use a wide-ranging [`_update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) too). Also note that you need to verify whether `cats` exist before `add`-ing a hashmap in there.

```
POST grille_badge/_update/1
{
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.cats instanceof List) { ctx._source.cats.add(params.cat) } else { ctx._source.cats = [params.cat] }",
    "params": {
      "cat": {
        "colors": 4,
        "name": "Leon",
        "breed": "Persian"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. Verify that `cats` are there:

```
GET grille_badge/_search
```

---

**EDIT & ELABORATION**

Here's how you do it:

```
POST grille_badge/_update/1
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
      
      def theme_target = ctx._source.theme.find(theme -> theme.name == params.current_theme);
      def categorie_target = theme_target.categories.find(categories -> categories.name == params.current_categorie);
      def niveau_target = categorie_target.niveaux.find(niveaux -> niveaux.name == params.current_niveau);
      def grille_target = niveau_target.grille_defis.find(grille_defis -> grille_defis.name == params.current_grille);
      
      grille_target['defis'].add(["name" : params['defis_ajouter']]);
    """,
    "params": {
      "current_theme": "foot",
      "current_categorie": "categorie1",
      "current_niveau": "bronze",
      "current_grille": "grille1",
      "defis_ajouter": "i am a defis"
    }
  }
}
```

Note the proper arrow notation in the `findAll` methods.

Also note that your own mapping defined the innermost `defis` as a `nested` array of key-value pairs -- this means you cannot push a plain string using the `.add` method -- you need to use a `HashMap`. You instatiate one with the one liner `["your_key" : "your_value"]`. Good luck.

Comment: hello there, my question is: how can i access the nested object "defis" to add some objects in it

Comment: all i saw in the documentation was to update a nested object, but how about updating a nested object inside of other nested objects

Comment: Please share your mapping of the index `grille_badge` in your question.

Comment: Done, i added the mapping of my index in the question

Comment: you can check now please